# JQuery running contains on this variable / object

Tags: javascript, jquery

OK I'm rather lost at this.
First i get a reference to a jquery li object using $this, then i try to use the "contains" jquery function to search within that li if some text exists. But the line with the "contains" never returns true.

```js
$("ul li").each(function(index) {
  var $this = $(this);

  //Attempt 1 using $this
  if ($this.is(":contains('some text' ) ")) {
    console.log(" matching free text found");
  } else {
    console.log(" matching free text not found");
  }
  //Attempt 2 using $(this)
  if ($(this).is(":contains('some text' ) ")) {
    console.log(" matching free text found");
  } else {
    console.log(" matching free text not found");
  }


})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>some text here</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to remove the ' ' from the :contains(some text).

jQuery documentation:
[jQuery - contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```js
$("ul li").each(function(index) {
  var $this = $(this);

  //Attempt 1 using $this
  if ($this.is(":contains(some text) ")) {
    console.log(" matching free text found at Index: " + index);
  } else {
    console.log(" matching free text not found");
  }
  //Attempt 2 using $(this)
  if ($(this).is(":contains(some text ) ")) {
    console.log(" matching free text found at index: " + index);
  } else {
    console.log(" matching free text not found");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>some text here</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about jQuery (as I dropped using it years ago in favor of ES6), but this is easy to achieve using vanilla Javascript.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("ul li").forEach(function(li) {
  console.log(`matching free text${li.textContent.includes('some text') ? " " : " not "}found`);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>some text here</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `$(this).text()` to get current text of `li` and `String.includes(text)` to check text exists in String.

```js
$("ul li").each(function(index) {
  var _this = $(this);

  //Attempt 1 using $this
  if (_this.text().includes('some text'))) {
    console.log("matching free text found");
  } else {
    console.log("matching free text not found");
  }
})
```